# Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line

Tags: c#

I am getting the error `Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line.` What I need to change in the code to make it work?

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[21] { new DataColumn("Siebel_SR#"),
          new DataColumn("Siebel_SR#1"), new DataColumn("Tran_Qty"), new DataColumn("Ord_Sou_Ref"),
          new DataColumn("Tran_Reference"), new DataColumn("[Ord Number]"), new DataColumn("[Ord Number1]"),
          new DataColumn("Transaction_Type_Id"), new DataColumn("Trans_Date"), new DataColumn("[Trans Sub]"),
          new DataColumn("Business"), new DataColumn("New_DFF_SR#"), new DataColumn("Reason_Name"),
          new DataColumn("Line_Type"), new DataColumn("Org"), new DataColumn("Sub_Inv"), new DataColumn("Part_Num"),
          new DataColumn("[Last Updated By]"), new DataColumn("[Created By]"), new DataColumn("Employee"), new DataColumn("DateWorked") }); 
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
            {
                CheckBox chk = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkSelect") as CheckBox);
                if (chk.Checked)
                {
                    string Siebel_SR# = row.Cells[2].Text;
                    string Tran_Qty = row.Cells[3].Text;
                    string Ord_Sou_Ref= row.Cells[4].Text;
                    string Tran_Reference = row.Cells[5].Text;

                    string Transaction_Type_Id = row.Cells[8].Text;
                    string Trans_Date = row.Cells[9].Text;

                    string Business = row.Cells[11].Text;

                    string Reason_Name = row.Cells[13].Text;
                    string Line_Type = row.Cells[14].Text;
                    string Org = row.Cells[15].Text;
                    string Sub_Inv = row.Cells[16].Text;
                    string Part_Num = row.Cells[17].Text;


                    string Employee = row.Cells[20].Text;
                    string DateWorked = row.Cells[21].Text;

                    dt.Rows.Add( Tran_Qty ,Ord_Sou_Ref , Tran_Reference , Transaction_Type_Id, Trans_Date ,
                     Business , Reason_Name ,Line_Type , Org , Sub_Inv , Part_Num , Employee , DateWorked  );
                }
            }
        }
        GridView3.DataSource = dt;
        GridView3.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Edit your post and put your question and if at all possible, your error.  Also, tag this for your programming language.

Comment: I can't but wonder, how does one get 2K reputation without learning the very basics of how to ask a question at SO?

Comment: This may help C# Preprocessor Directives: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx

Comment: @hyde: that wasn't me a friend of mine posted this question.C# isn't even what I work on, I'm an iOS developer.

Comment: @Ankur Well, I'm not sure what is SO view on account sharing if done responsibly, but considering how SO accounts are free to create, and how you can ask a question even without creating an account, and how this friend of yours doesn't know the basic conduct at SO, I'd educate them a bit before letting them use your account again...

Comment: @Ankur also, you should probably edit the question to be properly formatted. At least split those obscenely long lines, and move the question from a comment to the... question. And most importantly, get your friend to point out the line where the error is reported.

Comment: @hyde: Sure will tell him the basics. `P.S.`edited the question, I hope it's okay now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C# preprocessor directives begin with `#`, such as `#if` `#define` `#region` etc.  Each must be on its own line.  Even putting a comment in front of one will yield this error.

For example:

```
/* some comment*/ #region SOMETHING 

#endregion
```

will give this error because `#region` must not have anything (other than possibly whitespace) before it.